# Producing and capturing closed caption data with `AVCaptureSession`

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avcapturesession, closed-captions, coremediaio

I noticed that when capturing media with `AVCaptureSession` from an iPhone connected over USB to a mac that there is also a closed caption input (`AVMediaTypeClosedCaption = 'clcp'`):

```
"<AVCaptureInputPort: 0x60000003c260 (AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x6000002497e0) vide 0000 enabled>",
"<AVCaptureInputPort: 0x60000003c270 (AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x6000002497e0) soun 0000 enabled>",
"<AVCaptureInputPort: 0x60000003c280 (AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x6000002497e0) clcp 0000 enabled>"
```

The problem is I don't know how to capture closed caption data or even produce it.

For capture my first guess would be to add an `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` but that isn't available on `macOS`. `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` seems to consume any inputs it understands, but I can't see any closed caption data in the resulting file. Maybe because I don't know how to produce it on the iPhone.

For producing, I have tried turning on Voice Over and playing back media with subtitles with no obvious results.